# Loop prints same statement multipule times on same line

Tags: c++

This question seems very trivial but need help with my for loop printing the same thing on the same line separated by a space.

```
    int i;
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    cout << "Can you help me print this on the same line with spaces." << endl;
```

Comment: What do you think `endl` does?

Comment: You want to print that sentence out 3 times on the same line? In that case remove the `endl` and replace it with ' '

Comment: just to get into good habits, instead of `int i; for (i = 0; ...`, write `for( int i = 0; ...`. this limits the scope of the variable `i` so that it's not accessible after the loop. that prevents inadvertent use of it.

Comment: Clears add goes to a newline but if when I tried taking it out and wants the syntax that is missing

Comment: move the `endl` thing out of the loop.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf thank you I have changed it and I will remember that with future use

Comment: @TheDark doing so creates empty character constant. I am return 0 after the last piece of code.

Comment: It is a bit hard to spot in a browser (I should have marked it as code), but I typed `' '`  not `''`. Note: It would be better to just add the space to the end of the string in your case, but printing out the space separately would be needed if you couldn't change the string.

Comment: @TheDark Oh, I see! Thank you for both of the ways. I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `endl` or rather, `std::endl` is what's creating a new line so just remove that from the loop and remember to leave a trailing space if you want them to be spaced.